# How can I get real elment by node id? react-native

Tags: react-native

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPress.bind(this)}>
  <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>CLOSE</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

_onPress(e) {
  console.log(e.nativeEvent.target);
}
```

As above, the `target` is just a number called node id, but I want to get the real element. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code to do it changed recently when React / React Native common code was moved around, but what I would suggest is to [check out `Inspector` code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Inspector/InspectorUtils.js) and [available methods](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/native/ReactNativeComponentTree.js) on the `ReactNativeComponentTree`

More specifically, the following code should do the trick for you:

```
var ReactNativeComponentTree = require('react/lib/ReactNativeComponentTree');
ReactNativeComponentTree.getInstanceFromNode(nativeTag);
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for version 0.40 react native?

Comment: I saw this in the React source code. ` ReactDOM.render(<div><p>Hi.</p></div>, node);
var inst = ReactDOMComponentTree.getInstanceFromNode(node.firstChild);` from https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/efaa26eb50169aba7f9194119faf64b67cbff460/src/renderers/shared/hooks/__tests__/ReactHostOperationHistoryHook-test.js

Comment: for me it required to access the attribute _currentElement to e.g. access props

Comment: This was always a private API, and it no longer works in the latest RN versions.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I ended up resolving similar situation for myself.  It doesn't follow the same approach by any means but did it the trick!

```
onItemPressed(item) {
  this.props.navigateForward(item.sceneId);
  this.props.closeDrawer();
}

render() {
  var listItems = [];

  for (var i=0; i < this.props.navigation.scenes.length; i++) {
    var item = this.props.navigation.scenes[i];

    listItems.push(<ListItem
      onPress={this.onItemPressed.bind(this, item)}
      key={i}
      title={item.title}
      leftIcon={{name: item.icon}}
      underlayColor={colors.lightPrimary}
      containerStyle={styles.menuItemStyle}
      titleStyle={styles.menuItemTitle}
    />);
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <List containerStyle={styles.listContainer}>
        {listItems}
      </List>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Comment: This approach previously was acceptable but now the convention is to avoid passing newly created functions for every render cycle as it is a high performance cost due to the closure and the due to the reference being the different every time (thus triggering a render).

Comment: I think this is a better solution then the accepted one. But there should be even better one.

Comment: @eremzeit you can use shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {if (this.props... !== nextProps....) { return true; } return false;} to avoid redundant renders.

Answer (score 6):

In case somebody stumbles on that question, `ReactNativeComponentTree` was removed from version 0.56 or so.

However, I found a much cleaner way to detect a tap on a certain (sub-)element:

```js
import React from 'React';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,

  findNodeHandle
} from 'react-native';

class TestClass extends React.Component {
  onTap = (evt) => {
    // Retrieve the handle of the second <Text> node
    let elementHandle = findNodeHandle(this.refs["element"]);

    // Check if the tapped element's node-id equals the retrieved one 
    if (evt.nativeEvent.target == elementHandle) {
      // Do something when element was clicked
      console.log("Second <Text> node was tapped")
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onTap}>
        <View>
          <Text>Hi there!</Text>
          <Text ref="element">Only detect this element</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
};
```

Basically, we are just using a reference (`ref`) to access the node-id of an element using `findNodeHandle`.

We then compare that node-id with the `nativeEvent.target` node-id in order to check if a sub-element was tapped.

In the above example, only the second `<Text>` node produces an output.

Comment: This seems like it should be the accepted answer, and it appears to be the correct way for react-native.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't have access to the child to set the ref, this doesn't work. I ended up patching Pressability class method in runtime earlier in call stack to get access to the event. From there I have to yet find a way to resolve an element by node id, but at least I get access to all element props.

Answer (score 4):

In react native v.0.51 you need this statement:

```
import ReactNativeComponentTree from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree';
ReactNativeComponentTree.getInstanceFromNode(e.target);
```

and `._currentElement.props` changed to `.memoizedProps`

Comment: The feature has been removed in the latest version RN. I think react native's support in accessing native DOM element is very limited, and it needs to be improved.
Otherwise, every time when we use callback function, the argument 'this' cannot be well inspected and used.

Answer (score 1):

In react native v.0.42 you need this statement:

```
import ReactNativeComponentTree from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/native/ReactNativeComponentTree';
ReactNativeComponentTree.getInstanceFromNode(e.target)._currentElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem in question is by using a ref (together with createRef) like so:

```
  const touchableRef = React.createRef();
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      ref={touchableRef}
      onPress={() => /* use touchableRef.current */ undefined}
    />
  );
```

Another advantage of doing that is that the ref can be really anything, doesn't have to be the touched node.

Answer (score 0):

The concern is about performance so I solve it with this approach

just create a wrapper around TouchableOpacity or any clickable view

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"

export const TouchableOpacityOnPressOptimized = ({ children, onPress, index }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(index)}>
      {children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

const touchMe = (index) => {
    switch(index) {
       case 1: alert('index is' + index)
       case 2: alert('index is' + index)
    }
}

<TouchableOpacityOnPressOptimized index={1} onPress={touchMe}> touch me 1 </TouchableOpacityOnPressOptimized>

<TouchableOpacityOnPressOptimized index={2} onPress={touchMe}> touch me 2 </TouchableOpacityOnPressOptimized>

<TouchableOpacityOnPressOptimized index={3} onPress={touchMe}> touch me 3 </TouchableOpacityOnPressOptimized>
```

this way your touchable component not re-render

Answer (score 0):

From the React Native documentation: *"`findNodeHandle` won’t be compatible with React 18 once we are ready to roll that out. Deprecation of `findNodeHandle` in React Native is similar to the [deprecation of findDOMNode in React DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-deprecated-finddomnode-usage)."*

I'm very interested to find a better method to get the component when receiving a native event from a [press touch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/pressevent), for example.

I want have just only one event handler method and let it decide which component was the one who triggered the event... But not very fond of passing an [arrow function](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36) or using bind like the [proposed alternatives in the `No longer expose ReactNativeComponentTree`](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/12904) pull request.