# How do I check for the target of a touch event in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I have an `Image` inside a `TouchableOpacity`:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}
    onPress={(evt) => this._handlePress(evt)}>
        <Image
            style={{flex: 1, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
            source={require('./HumanBody.png')}
            ref='image' />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I'm trying to do different things depending on where the user taps on the `Image`. So I pass the touch event to my `_handlePress` function in order to use the coordinates where the tap happened.

I quickly realized that the Image and the surrounding `TouchableOpacity` have their own separate coordinate systems, so I can't tell from the coordinates whether the tap was inside the `Image` or in the surrounding space of the `TouchableOpacity`, so I need to consider the target of the event, which leaves me with a node ID. Now I need to check whether it belongs to my `Image`.

My current workaround is that I found out my `Image`'s node ID through testing and hard-coded it into my if statement.

```
_handlePress = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    this.setState({ x: evt.nativeEvent.locationX, y: evt.nativeEvent.locationY, target: evt.nativeEvent.target})
    this.refs['image'].measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
        let x = this.state.x
        let y = this.state.y
        let target = this.state.target
        if (target != 2) {
            // not inside the Image
        } else {
            // inside the Image
        }
    })
}
```

(The `.measure`ing might not be necessary in the end)

This is obviously awful and not a viable solution as the `Image`'s node ID will change whenever I change my home screen's structure or possibly even for changes that are completely out of my control. So I need some way to either get my `Image`'s node ID at run-time or to get an object from the target node ID.

Of course I found this (and nothing else that even remotely targets my problem): [How can I get real elment by node id? react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38651770/9903008)

The best answer did not work for me (the `require`d module could not be found).

The following `import`

```
import ReactNativeComponentTree from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree'
```

and then this in `_handlePress`

```
let target = ReactNativeComponentTree.getInstanceFromNode(this.state.target)
```

does kinda work but it leaves me with a `FiberNode` object and I have no idea how to check whether it belongs to my `Image` or not. I could find nothing about that.

So how do I find out whether the target is my `Image` (or *an* `Image` would suffice if there's a way for that)?

Comment: Did you tried to have the TouchableOpacity as the Image child? Should work without pain.

Comment: I tried it now and I get "Error: The <Image> component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using the <ImageBackground> component or absolute positioning."

Comment: Try to use <ImageBackground> then :)

Comment: It kinda works, but <ImageBackground> apparently lacks the `resizeMode` style prop, so it gets cropped to fill the whole screen. I need it to be fully displayed, just resized to fit the screen leaving the aspect ratio intact. I'll either need a different solution or I'll have to find a way to fit a `BackgroundImage`...

Comment: I've found a way: I had to use the `imageStyle` prop for the `BackgroundImage`, otherwise I styled the containing `View`.

Comment: And of course I meant `ImageBackground` in my previous two comments